# jQuery alphabetical only with numeric

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, numeric, alphabetical

I'm having some difficulties with JQuery validation. I need to make an input validation *alphabetical with numeric*, but it shouldn't be validate if I put only *numeric* value.

For example: **lorem ipsum 123** should be valid, **lorem ipsum** should be valid, **123** shouldn't be valid.

I use this code but it doesn't work properly.

```
e.find('.alphanum').keypress(function(e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might also be useful:

```
/^(?:[A-Za-z0-9 ]*[a-zA-Z ][0-9]*)+$/
```

It does almost the same thing as the one provided by Qwertiy, but might be simpler to understand (which, IMHO, is a quality in itself when it comes to regular expressions...).

What happens is that we form a non-capturing group of zero or more allowed characters, one required character, and then zero or more allowed but not required characters, and then we match that group. If you don't want to allow only-whitespace strings either, move the space from the second to third character class, i.e.

```
/^(?:[A-Za-z0-9 ]*[a-zA-Z][0-9 ]*)+$/
```

You can think of the three character classes as

1. All the characters that are allowed in the string.
2. All the characters that *must* occur at least once
3. All the characters that appear in 1., but not in 2.

It's very possible that this is more inefficient than Qwertiy's answer, but that solution also matches e.g. `"   "`, while the second one in this answer doesn't.

You can fiddle with the regex, and test the results, here: https://regex101.com/r/iB6pE1/3

Comment: +1 for the exposition; however, Qwerity's regex only needs 1 character added to avoid matching just spaces; I'm not sure it justifies the additional load/complexity.

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
/(?!^\d*$)^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/
```

Comment: Not explicitly stated in the question, but `(?!^[0-9 ]*$)^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$` might be closer to the intended behavior (i.e. include spaces in the negative lookahead, so "123 " or "1 2 3" for example aren't accepted).

Comment: my mistake. I check only which symbols I put on keyboard. But I should check this input and validate if alpha is missing